# ‘AnyHashable’ is not convertible to ‘NSObject’

Tags: swift, xcode

I am converting mine Objective-C code to Swift.
I am having my own DataStructure class called “DCclass" inherrited from  "NSObject"... 
i have done all required things like: In Bridging-header imported the “DCclass.h" and etc things fine but while having its for in loop i am facing error something like its type conversion issue.
Thanks In Advance.

Current Objective-C code:

```
#import “DCclass.h”
@interface LPFPickerCell ()
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
@end

@implementation LPFPickerCell
- (void)setSelectedData:(NSString *) selectedString
{    
    int i = 0;
    for (DCclass *dc in self.myMutableArray)    /// Swift is showing compile time error here
    {
        NSLog(@"DCclass.empName = %@",dc.empName);
    }
}
@end
```

Converted Swift Code:

```
class LPFPickerCell {

    var myMutableArray = [AnyHashable]()

    func setSelectedData(_ selectedString: String?) {
        let i: Int = 0
        for dc: DCclass in myMutableArray {    ///‘AnyHashable’ is not convertible to ‘DCclass’
        print("DCclass.empName = \(dc.empName)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to change your array type

```
var myMutableArray = [AnyHashable]()
```

to

```
var myMutableArray = [DCclass]()
```

And then in the for loop you can access it like this

```
for dc in myMutableArray {    
    print("DCclass.empName = \(dc.empName)")
}
```

Comment: First of all Thanks for the Answer...

But Actually i forget to mention that i am already using myMutableArray in the setter function... assigning the parameter passed to myMutableArray.. as:

Objective-C:
- (void)setmyMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *) mutArraa
{
    self.myMutableArray = mutArray;
}

Swift:
func setMyMutableArray(_ mutArray: [AnyHashable]?)
{
     myMutableArray = mutArray
}

So, should i have to typecast at that place? or anything else please let me know?

Comment: Yeah change the setter for myMutableArray `func setMyMutableArray(_ mutArray: [AnyHashable]?) { myMutableArray = mutArray }` to `func setMyMutableArray(_ mutArray: [DCclass]?) { myMutableArray = mutArray }`

Comment: @Nirmal happy to help you

Comment: Hello, Dioniz B...!!! I have posted new Question, if you can reply that also please...

Answer (score 1):

> The AnyHashable type forwards equality comparisons and hashing operations to an underlying hashable value, hiding its specific underlying type.
>
> You can store mixed-type keys in dictionaries and other collections that require Hashable conformance by wrapping mixed-type keys in AnyHashable instances:

Problem is that using `AnyHashable` will not work for type `DCclass` and so you need to manually cast the `myMutableArray` to particular type:

```
var myMutableArray = [DCclass]()
```

Convert code would be like:

```
class LPFPickerCell {
    var myMutableArray = [DCclass]()
  
    func setSelectedData(_ selectedString: String?) {
        let i: Int = 0
        for dc: DCclass in myMutableArray {  
            print("DCclass.empName = \(dc.empName)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all Thanks for the Answer...

But Actually i forget to mention that i am already using myMutableArray in the setter function... assigning the parameter passed to myMutableArray.. as:

Objective-C:
- (void)setmyMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *) mutArraa
{
    self.myMutableArray = mutArray;
}

Swift:
func setMyMutableArray(_ mutArray: [AnyHashable]?)
{
     myMutableArray = mutArray
}

So, should i have to typecast at that place? or anything else please let me know?